# Need remote desktop control via web browser, can't install any software on remote PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I need remote desktop from my work PC to my home PC.....Windows 7 at work, Windows XP at home.

My work PC has admin rights blocked, so I can't install Chrome Remote Desktop, TeamViewer or any other similar software at work.

I've tried a program called Firnass.com, but it does not seem to consistently work right......if there is some other Java based access, or something else, I would appreciate the help....thanks.

Comment: There's a reason your work's IT staff disabled those abilities.  Work with them instead of trying to circumvent them, as you are potentially opening their network up to security problems by doing what you seek, and if they find you're doing that, you may be looking for a new job.  anyhow, as is this is too broad, and/or just a software request which would be off-topic. Voting to close.

Comment: Teamviewer has a web portal. Anyway this is off-topic.

Comment: As mentioned by Raystafarian and ChrisinNL, Teamviewer has a portable version that does not require you to install. So you can have it running on a USB on your work PC without the need to install, and you can have it running permanently at your home machine (running as a service)

Answer (score 0):

This normally works in most companies. Forgive me if I missed something. It's been probably a decade since I used it.

1. Install RealVNC as it allows your to connect to your home computer at work via your browser
2. Once installed, set the default port to your web service on port **443** Check the application settings
3. Open your ports on your router to allow traffic to your machine on port 443
4. Get your external IP address
5. Navigate to: http://:443 from another machine outside your home network

If all went well, the browser will load a login page.

It's difficult and uncommon to keep port 443 closed in work environments.

btw: team viewer has a portable version